# How do I create a task to obtain something with cost in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I would like to setup a project that allows me to keep track of obtaining equipment for a business. Basically I the "progress" is the funds generated or the equipment obtained(e.g., if I stole it then I wouldn't need any funds).

There is many pieces of equipment and they affect other tasks(need the equipment before some tasks can complete).

e.g., I need to obtain the equipment "hypersupergizmocapacitorator" that costs about 10k$. I give myself about 6 months(may take longer or shorter) to obtain. Once I get that I can then do tasks that require it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of questions come to mind:

- Do you need to track the 6 month long process of obtaining the
  equipment or just the moment the equipment is available for use?

If you need to track the process, create the task or tasks leading up to them with you assigned as the resource.  Add a milestone "Equipment on site" as the successor to the process tasks.  You can then use that milestone as the predecessor to the tasks that require the equipment.

If you don't need to track the process - add a milestone "Equipment on site" with a constraint that you can change as needed.

- Is the cost for the equipment (10k) all charged back to the project?

In many circumstances, the capital costs would be amortized over a longer period of time - not just the project.  If the entire cost accrues to your project and you want to account for the point in time the 10K is paid, use the Fixed Cost field and assign the money to the "Equipment on site" task.

If you need to spread the costs over the life-span of the project (from beginning to end) create a Budget Cost type resource and assign it to the Project Summary task.

Answer (score 0):

Load them the same way you do human resources; instead of putting an hourly rate, use the cost/use column and load the $10K.  When you load the resource against the package, it will affect the planned value, or BCWS, accordingly.  When you purchase it, you can load actual costs and take your EV, just like you do for other type packages.  If AC differed from its PV and EV, you will show a variance.

Comment: Using the "Cost Per Use" field will cause the 10K to be assigned each time the equipment is used.

Comment: If you load the particular piece of equipment against several packages, can you not allocate portions of the total cost across those packages?  But, the way the OP described, it sounded as if he wanted to only show the package when procured, and perhaps as a predecessing milestone to the next package.  I think the cost/use column is appropriate here.

Comment: The cost per use is a flat rate.  Using a Cost type resource would allow differing costs per assignment.  The risk with the cost per use is assigning the equipment more than once.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean if you wish to allocate different costs of the piece of equipment against the different packages?  Very good point.  Thanks for setting me straight on this.

Comment: You're welcome.  Thank you for all you do!